# How much is should pay and from where I can find tools to develop for IPhone and IPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode

I am new to mac dev world. every where i try to download or do something i find "you should pay $99".

I want xcode to develop these apps, and test them before putting on the market place.

how much i should pay in total and from where I can download this xcode to start programming?

please provide me with links.

Comment: Questions regarding programming and Apple Developer Program are defined offtopic by the FAQ. You could start by reading up on [xCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This website](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) contains registration information for iOS & Mac development. You can develop apps on your Mac for free but in order to test them on your iPhone or sell them on the App Store you will need to pay the $99/year fee.

Comment: I don't want to test on real IPhone, from where i can download xcode for my leopard?

Comment: developer.apple.com has all this information.

Comment: found it after login there: https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792   thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well... it's not really $99. It is $99 per year.

To start programming for the iPhone you need to :

- [Get a Mac](http://store.apple.com/us) (if you don't have one)
- Download [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

You can use Xcode to develop your application and test it on the iPhone and iPad simulator which comes with Xcode.

If you want to be able to download the documentation and developer resources you need to:

- register for an [Apple Developer ID](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) (free).

To be able to test your applications directly on physical iPhones/iPads and be able to publish them on the App Store you need to:

- enroll into the [iOS developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/) ($99/year).

You can wait to enroll only when you are ready to properly test your application on the devices.